# * on the linux command line

Tags: c, linux

I am making a little calculator in C, and i want to pass simple arithmetic formulae to my program. But it really does not like me passing character '*' to my program. 
Why not?
And how can I work around this without changing the asterix to something else?
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The character `*` is the shell's trigger for expanding matching filenames.

There are several ways to deal with it:

- Escape it when typing   `mycalc 5 \* 3`
- Place the whole expression in quotes and make sure the calculator's parser works that way:  `myprog "5 * 3"`
- Don't use the command line:  use your own input instead.

Comment: OR: always run it in an empty directory :)

Comment: Interesting idea.  It could be marketed as a dedicated *calculation directory*.  Or maybe a *secure calculation environment*.  :-)

Comment: Depends on the shell.  While Bash, by default, leaves a glob unexpanded if it matches nothing, it can be configured to remove a glob (`shopt -s nullglob`) or fail the whole command (`shopt -s failglob`).  In other shells, `tcsh` for example, the last behavior is the default.

Answer (score 7):

`*` gets expanded to match all files in the current directory (this is called "globbing"). You need to quote or escape the *, or use a different symbol.

Answer (score 6):

* will invoke globbing and expand to all files in the directory you're in. Just quote the * and run your program like

`./yourprogram '10 * 10'`

or

`./yourprogram 10 '*' 10`

With the first case, your program will get passed only 1 argument, argv[1] will be the string "10 * 10" , the second case you'll get passed 3 arguments

Answer (score 3):

The Linux command shell (bash, tcsh, ksh, whatever) will expand the '*' into a list of files before your program even sees it.  There's very little you can do about that - you could have the users put the asterisk in single quotes, or escape it with a backslash, or use 'x' instead.  None is particularly user friendly.

Answer (score 2):

One last technique not mentioned.  Insteead of quoting/escaping every usage, you can turn off globbing.  This way, if you want to use the calculator a lot, you don't have to escape every usage:

```
# For bash
set -o noglob

# For csh/tcsh
set noglob

# Now that noglob is set, you can safely use *
calc 3 * 3
```

Comment: +1 - Its better to run 'calc' in a wrapper script so that the user can  enjoy more natural language input. Also very useful when piping input from a file.

Answer (score 1):

`*` evaluates to "everything in the current directory" under bash. However, `.` works correctly and is often used as a symbol for multiplication in mathematics - specifically scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

The "calc" application that you can retrieve from deb repositories apt-get install calc can evaluate 3*3 but not 3 * 3

Answer (score -1):

Try escaping it, the asterisk is a special character in C

Change * to \*